# dynamic fields in iphone passbook pass

Tags: iphone, passbook

I integrated passbook with my application. I need some of the pass fields as dynamic. How can I create Pass using dynamic values using passkit framework?

Comment: elaborate the question to clear what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passkit is the device-side library used to view and manipulate passes. You can't use it to generate passes - this needs to happen outside the device, using your own tools. Apple provide some sample code in Ruby that shows you how to sign and create passes.

I would suggest you take a look at Apple's [Pass Design and Creation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW1) document, which runs through how to create a pass, sign it, and update it. The updating of passes is what makes a field dynamic.

Comment: I didnt found that ruby sample code, can you please provide the link?

Comment: It's here, under "Passbook Support Materials": https://developer.apple.com/passbook/

Comment: oh. that sign pass code,right? By using that is it possible to add dynamic field in pass.json file?

Comment: Like I said, there's no difference in the pass.json file between static and dynamic fields. Dynamic fields are fields that you later update by creating a new payload (which includes pass.json).

Comment: what about the dynamic setting of a field which is left empty. how to deal with those

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, anything that you place inside the pass.json with the exception of the `passTypeIdentifier` and `serialNumber` is dynamic, in the sense that it can be replaced with a new value or removed.

This is because in order to update a pass, Passbook needs a complete .pkpass bundle.  Since the whole bundle is provided, everything inside it is available to be changed with the execpetion of the `passTypeIdentifier` and `serialNumber` which are used by Passbook to identify the pass as the one being updated.

Although Apple strongly advise against it, in theory a coupon for cookies could be replaced by a boarding pass from JFK to LAX.